# Appending an excel file using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, automation, etl, openpyxl

I have a file as follows.

> None | None | None | None | None | None |  None | None | None | None |
>   None | None |  None | None | Category | Values | None | None |  None |
>   None | DISC | DISC | NON_DISC | NON_DISC |  EMPLOYEE_ID |
>   Creation_Date | **COUNTS** | DOLLARS | **COUNTS** | DOLLARS |

I want to transform it as follows.

> EMPLOYEE_ID | Creation_Date | DISC COUNTS | DISC DOLLARS | NON_DISC
>   COUNTS | NON_DISC DOLLARS |

I have used following functions

> ```
> # for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, min_col=1, max_row=10, max_col=7):
> #     for cell in row:
> #         if cell.value == "COUNTS":
> #             cell.value ="DISC COUNTS"
> #         if cell.value == "DOLLARS":
> #             cell.value = "DISC DOLLARS"
> #         if cell.value == "COUNTS":
> #             cell.value = "NON_DISC COUNTS"
> #         if cell.value == "DOLLARS":
> #             cell.value = "NON_DISC DOLLARS"
> #     print()
> ```

The Irony is there is **count** couple of times. Hence, this methodology fails.

I get this file every week and have to make few changes in it and upload it to a server to feed a monthly report data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you be more clear as to what you're asking?

Comment: what exactly was unclear

Comment: This might be a quick way to dot it. Open file in excel and rename columns like - counts1 and counts2. And change your code accordingly.

Comment: Which column do you want? It looks like you want `ws[1][-6:]`. Just use a positional index.

Comment: @RamanvirSodhi The entire motive behind the effort was to avoid any manual work using excel. There should be a way.

Comment: Read about [Inserting and deleting rows and columns, moving ranges of cells](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/editing_worksheets.html?highlight=delete%20column)